# Button to change the rendered partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3. I have a page with several div blocks. I am trying to seperate them into two pages. I want a button at the bottom of the page which will change the rendered partial.

The "render 'news'" is the first partial loaded. I want the "Archived News Postings" button to change the 'news' to 'archive_news'

```
<%= render 'news' %>
<%= link_to render(:partial => 'archive_news'), :class => 'btn' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="archive">Archived News Postings</button>
```

Can I get a pointer? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve really. For instance, these two options could be considered:

1) You could fetch both the news items and the archived ones. Then render two divs with the corresponding news items. The one with news is shown while the other has `display: none;` in the CSS. This allows you to use JavaScript to toggle the divs visibility. This obviously has some disadvantages with amount of data etc. but it gives an idea what to think about.

Something along these lines:

controller:

```
def some_action
  @items = ...
  @archived_items = ...
end
```

view:

```
<div id="news">
  <% @items.each do |i|
    ...
</div>

<div id="archived_news">
  <% @archived_items.each do |i|
    ...
</div>
```

css:

```
#archived_news {
  display: none;
}
```

2) Another way would be to rely on asynchronously fetching the news items as the used wants to "toggle". This can be done with AJAX. This allows for more flexibility if the data set is large. You can even have "fetch more" in some way that archived news items are loaded on demand if needed.

If you shed some light what you might need it is possible to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Both would work actually. I like your idea of fetching the news items as a toggle. But I have no knowledge of AJAX.

Comment: If what you're doing is very simple and/or if the data sets are small, alternative 1 is easy and straight-forward.

Comment: Would I be able to just place the render 'news' in a div and use Javascript to hide and how them?

Comment: @DDDD: I updated the answer with some directions. Then you need a link to e.g. jQuery that toggles the divs.